# FriendPickerSample Installation failed due to invalid APK file! [ FriendPickerSample]

Tags: android, facebook

I got the error in console while working with `facebook sdk` samples.I have checked the logcat.The error in `logcat` and `console` is given below.

In **Console**:

> [2013-12-05 17:36:05 - FriendPickerSample] Installation failed due to
>   invalid APK file! [2013-12-05 17:36:05 - FriendPickerSample] Please
>   check logcat output for more details. [2013-12-05 17:36:05 -
>   FriendPickerSample] Launch canceled

In **Logcat**:

> 12-05 17:42:02.617: W/PackageParser(582): Unable to read
>   AndroidManifest.xml of /data/local/tmp/FriendPickerSample.apk 12-05
>   17:42:02.617: W/PackageParser(582): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   AndroidManifest.xml 12-05 17:42:02.617: W/PackageParser(582):     at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
>   12-05 17:42:02.617: W/PackageParser(582):     at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:487)
>   12-05 17:42:02.617: W/PackageParser(582):     at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlResourceParser(AssetManager.java:455)
>   12-05 17:42:02.617: W/PackageParser(582):     at
>   android.content.pm.PackageParser.parsePackageLite(PackageParser.java:722)
>   12-05 17:42:02.617: W/PackageParser(582):     at
>   com.android.defcontainer.DefaultContainerService$1.getMinimalPackageInfo(DefaultContainerService.java:169)
>   12-05 17:42:02.617: W/PackageParser(582):     at
>   com.android.internal.app.IMediaContainerService$Stub.onTransact(IMediaContainerService.java:110)
>   12-05 17:42:02.617: W/PackageParser(582):     at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367) 12-05 17:42:02.617:
>   W/PackageParser(582):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
>   12-05 17:42:02.617: W/DefContainer(582): Failed to parse package 12-05
>   17:42:02.627: W/ActivityManager(169): No content provider found for
>   permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/FriendPickerSample.apk

Comment: are u getting this error at first time?

Comment: yes i got this error for the first time

Answer (score -5, accepted):

now i got the solution for my question.i just simply follow the below link.It works fine

[facebook developers site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)

Answer (score 18):

I had same issue while working with Samples provided with Facebook SDK.
Finally I figured out issue by following these steps.

- Main cause of problem is libs folder (it is declared a link but depending of your folder configuration, it may be a broken link) which comes with projects, so delete it.

[image]

- Check in your project properties, -> Android, that your project has a reference to the library of the SDK (bottom part of the screen)

[image]

- Now clean and build project.

Also if someone looking for a simplest solution for facebook integration then i will prefer to use [Simple Facebook SDK](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook).

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this error few times during my Facebook sample application tests.
What you should do and helped me is:

1. Change the Project build Target API using -> Right Click on the project -> Properties -> Android.
2. Go to the bin folder of the project in it delete the already created apk file and then try to run the project again.

Comment: thanks you for your reply.but it shows same error.can you please suggest what i have to do

Comment: Try to perform a clean to you project after you remove the apk file, and then maybe try to run the application.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem here, you just have to import the projects without 'Copy projects into workspace' option enabled. If you already imported and copied them, hard-deleted them before the re-import.

I skipped that and got the same problem as you. Facebook Official tutorial says:

> You must unselect the 'Copy projects into workspace' option so that each of the sample projects retains a correct reference to the neighboring SDK.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Answer (score 1):

delete libs folder and clean the project and now run...

Answer (score 0):

my solution for the same problem was:

1. delete the libs folder from the HelloFacebookSample project
2. updating manifast.xml target sdk:
3. Adding library of v7&v4 support. That would be the "appcompat_v7" library project which is automatically created in eclipse when create new project.